# Flex: Wrapper for ResourceManager.getInstance().getString is not notified of localeChain updates

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, locale, resourcemanager

I have written a utility library that contains some of my most used functions. 
There I have a wrapper for ResourceManager.getString to simplify using the resource manager in non-UI classes:

```
package
{
    import mx.resources.ResourceManager;
    /**
     * Convenience function to return a localized string
     * */
    [Bindable("change")]
    public function _s(bundle:String, resourceName:String):String
    {
        return (ResourceManager.getInstance().getString(bundle, resourceName));
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when the localeChain is changed, the function won't get called, while when invoking `resourceManager.getString` everything works as expected.

Since it is just a wrapper, I can easily switch back to the "long" notation, but I'm curious how I would achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatley, the code Lance posted does not work. I have an updated version. However This cannot be used with a global public function, as I wanted it to work. It still has to be `included` in every file to be used. As such it is not really useful for a swc

```
// ActionScript file
import flash.events.Event;

/**
 * Convenience function to return a localized string

 * */
[Bindable("change")] 
public function _s(bundle:String, resourceName:String):String
{
    return (resourceManager.getString(bundle, resourceName));
}
override protected function createChildren():void
{
    super.createChildren();
    resourceManager.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, function(e:Event):void {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));     
        } 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind to the ResourceManager's change event, and redispatch it to execute bindings for `_s`.  Something like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;

import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
import mx.resources.IResourceManager;
import mx.resources.ResourceManager;

/**
 * Convenience function to return a localized string
 * */
[Bindable("change")]
public function _s(bundle:String, resourceName:String):String
{
    return (resourceManager.getString(bundle, resourceName));
}

override protected function createChildren():void
{
    super.createChildren();
    BindingUtils.bindSetter(dispatchChange, resourceManager, "change");
}

private function dispatchChange(event:Event):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

That's just a sample include script (`include "resource_wrapper.as"`), it shouldn't work out of the box, but you could modify it however.

The only problem with `include` is that you have to include it in lots of files manually.  But that is the only way you can make it one "dot" deep:

- `include`: Makes it like `getString()` (or `_s()`);
- normal: Makes it like `resourceManager.getString()`
- singleton: Makes it like `ResourceManager.getInstance().getString()`

Hope that helps,
Lance